# Spring MVC REST POST or PUT correct data

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using **Spring MVC** to develop a **RESTful** API service. I created classes for objects to store so it's automatically parsed and serialized.

But a `POST` method requires some data validation. Are there any annotations to make property of a object required due parsing `POST`.

I'n using standard converters and didn't customized anything here. Data goes by `json` or `xml`. (my manipulations are simple and similar to [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) but with `POST` method)

Comment: Can you post your curent controller action code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can attach validation constraints (from `javax.validation`) to your DTO and then annotate it with `@Valid` in your controller-action method. For example:

```
public class PersonDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name is required")
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Then your controller action would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, ...)
public ResponseEntity<PersonDTO> create(@RequestBody @Valid PersonDTO personDTO, ..., Errors errors) {
    ...
}
```

This will automatically validate the request body, and any validation errors will be inside `errors`.